# Exclude one directory in `ls` matching pattern

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

I'm trying to `ls` dirs that have `.png` files inside (no need for recursiveness, though it would be extra useful), exept one. Exlude one directory i.e.

```
ls */*.png
```

works fine.

```
ls (^one)*/*.png
```

returns no stdout. How do I achieve it?

I am blind and piping it to `espeak`, so I can only hear stdout for now.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Your pattern looks like a zsh pattern, though not a useful one as it wouldn't exclude `one` (the right pattern would be `^one/*.png`), it would print everything.

Answer (score 16):

**Option 1** - using just `ls`: 
With extended bash globbing turned on (`shopt -s extglob`) you can do:

```
ls !(one*)/*.png
```

**Option 2** - combining `ls` and `grep`:

You can combine `ls` with `grep -v`

- e.g. `ls */*.png | grep -v "one/"`

**Option 3** - (the best IMO) but uses `find` not `ls`:

For recursive searching of all subdirectories using `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -not -path "*/one/*"
```

All of the above one-liners will list directories with `.png` files while filtering out any path matching `one/`; only Option 3 will do this recursively.

Comment: Doesn't the `find` command need to say `-path "*/one/*"` or `-path "./one/*"`?

Comment: @G-Man You're absolutely right. Edited above.

Comment: Wouldn't that still match `./phone/handset.png`?

Comment: @G-Man What's wrong with matching `.png`s in a directory called `phone`? I thought we were just trying to exclude `one`?

Comment: Well, since you're using it in connection with `-not`, it means that it causes the `find` to exclude files in a directory called `phone`.

Comment: @G-Man Ah! Edited above.

Answer (score 6):

In [zsh](http://www.zsh.org), put [`setopt extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) in your `~/.zshrc`. Then you can use the [wildcard pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) `^one` to exclude the directory called `one`.

```
ls ^one/*.png
```

If you want to recurse into subdirectories, use `**/` for recursive globbing. To exclude the directory called `one` at the toplevel, as well as the toplevel directory:

```
ls ^one/**/*.png
```

To exclude files in a subdirectory called `one`, but not files in subdirectories of it:

```
ls **/^one/*.png
```

To exclude files under a subdirectory called `one` at any level, use a repeat pattern with the `#` operator around the negation:

```
ls (^one/)#/*.png
```